# Fedora 25, Wayland, and HiDPI display

Tags: fedora, wayland

I just upgraded my ThinkPad T560 from Fedora 24 to Fedora 25.

On Fedora 24, I used these commands:

```
$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1.25x1.25
$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --panning 3600x2025
```

to set up proper scaling. These commands no longer work on Fedora 25:

```
$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1.25x1.25
warning: output eDP-1 not found; ignoring
```

Apparently the display identifier is now `XWAYLAND0` (and not `eDP-1` anymore):

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2880 x 1620, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 2880x1620+0+0 340mm x 190mm
   2880x1620     59.92*+
```

However, using this new identifier with the old command also does not work:

```
$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --scale 1.25x1.25
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  26 (RRSetCrtcTransform)
  Value in failed request:  0x20
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  23
```

As a short term solution I choose "GNOME on Xorg" on login. Then I can use the `xrandr` commands shown above as before.

Can somebody please point me to a how-to for properly setting up HiDPI displays on Fedora 25?

Comment: I can't say I am any sort of an expert on Wayland, but my understanding is that anything referring to X applies to XWayland, which is an X server running as a Wayland client. This means you have two kinds of windows: native Wayland application windows, and XWayland windows, which are legacy X application windows. X11 under Wayland is no longer related to the whole screen.

Answer (score 5):

GNOME Shell on Wayland — which is what Fedora 25 Workstation uses — does not support non-integer scaling factors. There's some preliminary work but nothing decided yet; right now, the workaround you already chose (fall back to X11) is the right one.

Alternately, you can choose an integer scaling factor and then use tweak-tool to change font sizes to make things more readable. That doesn't scale non-text elements, of course, but it gives a little more flexibility (and readability).

Answer (score 0):

This may be a starting point: according to this man page on the [weston.ini](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/weston.ini.5.html) file, there is a configuration option for the Weston compositor that you can put under a `[output]` section header:

```
 scale=factor
```

> An integer, 1 by default, typically configured as 2 when needed,
>      denoting the scale  factor  of  the  output.  Applications  that
>      support   it   render   at  the  appropriate  scale.  For  other
>      applications, weston will scale their output by this factor.
>      Use a value of 2 for outputs with high resolution. Such displays
>      are often called "HiDPI" or "retina" displays.

Comment: weston is not installed, hence `weston.ini` will have no effect